# Nodejs instances runs for 2 seconds and pauses for 30

Tags: node.js, performance-testing

In one NodeJS VM, I have 6 instances. When I hit all of the 6 instances separately and monitor all console logs together, it is observed that there is a flurry of activity on all console logs for 2 seconds, followed by a 30 second period of inactivity. This pattern repeats itself.

This cycle occurs at the exact same time for all 6 instances whether or not the start time of the Jmeter test is varied. The resulting tps is very low.

May I know if this behavior is normal to NodeJS or if some tuning needs to be done and if yes, what should be tuned?

Comment: Do you use setInterval in you code? What tool or native NodeJS code did you use to allow 6 parallel instances? Can you provide a relevant and meaningful snippet of code? At the moment we can only advance blind hypothesis..

Comment: Hi @AlbertoSchiabel no, setInterval is not used. Each instance is represented by one port in a virtual machine. Any code/APIs/combination of APIs triggered separately in each of the six instances causes the same behavior of activity followed by a long period of waiting - but the amount of time differs with the API (and therefore complexity). *Edit: Not sure how it would help, but here's a code snippet: exports.pinging = function (req, res, next) {
console.log('Pong'); var sendBack = {"ResultStatus" : {"StatusCode" : "Successful"}}; console.log('Pong'); res.status(200); res.json(sendBack);})}